# error in insert statement within a procedure

Tags: sql

```
create or replace procedure add1(id1 integer, id integer)
as
begin 
   execute immediate 'create table section2(id integer)';
   execute immediate 'insert into section2 values(id1)';
end;
```

displays

> [ERR-312BA : Column not allowed here:
>   0001 : insert into Section2 values(ID)
>                                    ^  ^

I want to insert directly not values but through variables

Comment: what rdbms do you use?

Comment: 'it's a korean database altibase isql '

Answer (score 1):

This is because `values` expects literal constants and parameters of the statement being executed. Although `id1` is a parameter, it belongs to the stored procedure, not to the `INSERT` statement.

Try this statement instead:

```
execute immediate 'INSERT INTO section2(id) VALUES (:1)' USING id1;
```

Now `id1` becomes a value of the parameter `:1`, so the statement should run correctly.